# UIPrintInteractionController - No document-format-supported attribute found or no supported formats found

Tags: ios, xcode, airprint, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I use airprint to print to a compatible airprint label printing device. When attempting to print a label, I sometimes get the following errors:

> No document-format-supported attribute found or no supported formats found.
>   No mediaColSupported found, defaulting to media-bottom-margin, media-left-margin, media-right-margin, media-size, and media-top-margin.
>   No print-quality-supported attribute found.  Defaulting to normal quality.
>   No sides-supported attribute found.  Defaulting to PKDuplexNone.

When this error pops up, the label comes out scaled wrong.
When this error doesn't pop up, the label comes out correctly.

Any help to point me in the right direction to solve this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that in some instances the printer doesn't respond which type of paper is installed. I solved this by specifying the paper type in the code.
Printer used: Brother QL-720NW.
I also have a ticket open with Brother for this and will update once I get a response.

Comment: I'm getting this error too.  Did you ever get a response from Brother?

Comment: Hi Chuck, this is due to a problem in the Brother software. I had to make a work-around.